# ios tableview with red(gradient) clear button

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to storyboard a fairly basic app.  It has a tableview with some group cells.  One of those groups I want to be a 'Clear' button with a red gradient background.  Look at email settings, for an individual account there is a 'Delete Account' button that is a red gradient.  What is the correct to add this to a table view when using storyboard.

What I have tried:

1.Just a normal table cell. This is not really a button although I could listen for a select on that cell.

2. Change the cell to custom, and add a button to the table cell.  I have to change the button to a custom button to get the border to hide.
3. Add a button to the bottom of the table view.  Issue here is that the button is wider than all the table cells.

Is there an easy way, or at least a right way to get a button that is the same size as all my table cells with a red gradient?

Added a screen shot of an example for the mail settings panel.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag and drop a view to bottom of your tableview, then drag and drop a button inside of that view.

You can resize that button like any other button, in button settings just choose your image file for the background of the button

[image]

[image]

**EDIT::::**

If you want them to be same background connect your view to a outlet and change the backgorund to same color:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *lowerView;
@synthesize lowerView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor=nil;

    self.lowerView.backgroundColor=nil;
}
```

Comment: I want the button to be part of the table, ie have the same background.  I posted a pic of an example.

Comment: NM, added the background for a grouped table to the view and it works great.  Thanks!